# orthonormal sequence in $L^2[0,1]$ - how to prove these following equivalent terms?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, orthonormal

I've been asked this following very interesting question and would like some help figuring out why it is true :)

Let $u_n$ be an orthonormal sequence in $L^2[0,1]$

Prove that the following are equivalent:

1. $u_n$ is complete (orthonormal basis)
2. for every $x\in [0,1]$ : $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\int_{0}^{x} u_n(t)dt|^2 $
3. $0.5=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} |\int_{0}^{x} u_n(t)dt|^2 dx $

My thoughts so far:

a. if $u_n$ is complete, I could use Parseval's identity with functions $f=1_{[0,x]}$ and get condition 2, and integrate it to get condition 3 (*p.s: why could I change the order of the inifite sum with that $\int_{0}^{1}$?*)

b. The other way aronud is harder. I figured out that using the definition of orthonormal basis would be a little difficult, So probably I'm supposed to show the Parsevals' identity, or something like that. no luck there.

I would like some guide if you could.

Thanks!

**Edit: I tried this question for a couple more hours and couldn't solve. A more direct hint would be appreciated.**

Comment: Might be I am confused: Shouldn't it be $(\int_0^x u_n(t) dt)^2$ instead of $\int_0^x |u_n(t)|^2dt$ for the Parseval's identity?

Comment: @John: Parseval's identity is: $\sum_n |\langle x, e_n\rangle|^2 = \|x\|^2$, so I think I'm right

Edit: I fixed the question, thanks. It is that, I just miss-typed. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thanks you.

Comment: Hint: (2) $\sum_{n}|\langle \chi_{[0,x]},u_n\rangle|^{2} \le \|\chi_{[0,x]}\|^{2}$ with equality for some $x\in[0,1]$ iff Parseval holds for $\chi_{[0,x]}$. (3) monotone convergence and (2).

Comment: hey @T.A.E. , thanks for the comment. It wasn't very clear to me though. I understand I can assume 2 and show indecators $1_{[0,x]}$ but it is not enough since I can't generally approximate $f\in L^2[0,1]$ by this kinds of indecators or simple functions, I'd need to be able to change the values in general $[a,b] \inclusion [0,1]$.

Regarding 3 - why is the monotone converges theorem relevant? what function and what series?

Comment: @Functional_Analysis : The linear subspace spanned by functions $\{ \chi_{[0,x]} : 0 \le x \le 1 \}$ is dense in $L^{2}[0,1]$. You can show this by proving that $(f,\chi_{[0,x]})=0$ for all $0 \le x \le 1$ iff $f=0$ a.e.. (Hint: Lebesgue's differentiation theorem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span $S$ of the functions $\{ \chi_{[0,x]} : 0 \le x \le 1\}$ is a dense linear subspace of the Hilbert space $L^{2}[0,1]$. To see that the span is dense, it is enough to show that $(f,\chi_{[0,x]})=0$ for all $x$ and some $f \in L^{2}[0,1]$ implies $f=0$. By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, the following holds a.e.:
$$
                  \frac{d}{dx}(f,\chi_{[0,x]})=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt = f(x).
$$
So it follows that $S$ is dense in $L^{2}[0,1]$.

Let $\{ u_{n} \}$ be an orthonormal subset of $L^{2}[0,1]$. Parseval's equality holds for a given $f$ with respect to this set iff $f$ is in the closed linear subspace $\mathcal{U}$ generated by this orthonormal subset, which means that $\{ u_{n} \}$ is a complete orthonormal subset iff $\mathcal{U}$ includes $S$. That is, $\{ u_{n} \}$ is complete iff
$$
\begin{align}
          x & = \int_{0}^{x}|\chi_{[0,x]}(t)|^{2}\,dt \\
            & = \sum_{n}^{\infty}|(\chi_{[0,x]},u_{n})|^{2} \\
            & =\sum_{n} \left|\int_{0}^{x}u_{n}(t)\,dt\right|^{2},\;\;\; 0 \le x \le 1.
\end{align}
$$
So that takes care of (1) $\iff$ (2).

For (2) $\iff$ (3), note that Bessel's inequality always holds:
$$
        \sum_{n}\left|\int_{0}^{x}u_{n}(t)\,dt\right|^{2} \le \int_{0}^{1}|\chi_{[0,x]}(t)|^{2}\,dx = x.
$$
Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection of $L^{2}[0,1]$ onto the closed linear span $\mathcal{U}$ of the $\{ u_{n} \}$. Then $x\mapsto P\chi_{[0,x]}$ is continuous because $x\mapsto \chi_{[0,x]}$ is continuous from $[0,1]$ into $L^{2}[0,1]$ (dominated convergence,) and because $P$ is continuous on $L^{2}[0,1]$. The left side above is $\|P\chi_{[0,x]}\|^{2}$, which must be continuous in $x$. The left side must equal $x$ for all $x$ in order for $\mathcal{U}$ to be complete. It follows that equality holds for all $x$ iff
$$
          \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n}\left|\int_{0}^{x}u_{n}(t)\,dt\right|^{2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
By monotone convergence, you are allowed to interchange summation and integration in order to conclude that the above holds iff
$$
                \sum_{n}\int_{0}^{1}\left|\int_{0}^{x}u_{n}(t)\,dt\right|^{2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed solution.
I didn't understand what comes after "It follows that equality holds for all x iff". Why does it follows from that?

I understand one direction, but not why it's iff

To be more precise, I didn't understand why "The left side must equal x for all x in order for U to be complete"

Comment: @Functional_Analysis : You have a continuous function $h$ such that $0 \le h(x) \le x$. If $h(y) < y$ for some $0 \le y \le 1$, then $\int h(x)\,dx < \int x\,dx = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks! is it correct though to talk about continuous function and use their very properties since we are in $L^2$ and everything is defined up to $\mu$-a.e equiality?

Comment: $x \in [0,1] \mapsto \chi_{[0,x]} \in L^{2}$ is a continuous function in norm. And $Pf=\sum_{n}(f,u_{n})u_{n}$ defines continuous $P : L^{2}\rightarrow L^{2}$. Therefore, $x \mapsto \|P \chi_{[0,x]}\|^{2} = \sum_{n}|\int_{0}^{x}u_{n}(t)|^{2}$ is continuous with respect to $x$. That's why $h$ as in comment above is continuous. I've been fairly careful about how I stated these things in order to avoid any necessary mention of a.e..

Comment: @Functional_Analysis : Summarizing. $x \mapsto \|P\chi_{[0,x]}\|^{2}$ is continuous as a real function. And this function--call it h--satisfies $0 \le h(x) \le x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. If $h(x) \ne x$ for some $y$ then $h(x) < x-\epsilon$ for all $x$ near $y$ (by continuity) and, therefore $\int h(x)\,dx < \int x\,dx = \frac{1}{2}$ must hold in that case. So $\int h(x)\,dx = 1/2$ if and only if $h(x)=x$ for all $x$, which is equivalent to Parseval holding for $\chi_{[0,x]}$ for all $x$, which is equivalent to $\{ u_{n} \}$ being complete. I know this is subtle, and that's why I posted.

Comment: That's very nice and accurate. Thanks, it was a great learning session.

Comment: I can't believe i'm still strugling.
why $∥Pχ[0,x]∥^2=$∑n∣∣∣∫x0un(t)dt∣∣∣2$?
you are writing the projection as sum of the inner-products of the basis of the closed-subspace, but as far as i know it is correct only for finite dimension spaces with orthonormal basis. in order to write the infinite sum we'd need the basis to be complete, which we of course don't know.

Comment: @Functional_Analysis : You know that $Px = \sum_{n}(x,u_{n})u_{n}$ always converges in the Hilbert space $L^{2}$ because of Bessel's inequality $\sum_{n}|(x,u_{n})|^{2} \le \|x\|^{2}$; this holds for any orthonormal subset, whether finite or infinite. Therefore, $\|Px\|^{2}=\sum_{n}|(x,u_{n})|^{2} \le \|x\|^{2}$. That's all you really need for this problem: continuity of $x\mapsto Px$. But you can determine that $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the closure of the linear span of the $\{ u_{n} \}$, even though that's not needed here; indeed, it easy to verify that $(x-Px)\perp u_{n}=0$.

Comment: @Functional_Analysis : $P_{k}f=\sum_{n=1}^{k}(f,u_{n})u_{n}$. Verify that $\|P_{k}f\|^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{k}|(f,u_{n})|^{2}$ and let $k\rightarrow\infty$ to obtain $\|Pf\|^{2}=\sum_{n}|(f,u_{n})|^{2}$. Let $f=\chi_{[0,x]}$. Then $(u_{n},f)=\int_{0}^{1}\chi_{[0,x]}(t)u_{n}(t)\,dt=\int_{0}^{x}u_{n}(t)\,dt$. So $\|P\chi_{[0,x]}\|^{2}=\sum_{n}|(f,u_{n})|^{2}=\sum_{n}|\int_{0}^{x}u_{n}(t)\,dt|^{2}$